# What database should I use for a data visualization app?

Tags: android, ios, database, flutter

I want to create an Android/iOS tablet app that will visualize data from a number of desktop apps that have the same function (facilitating orienteering events) but may be very different in their construction. The idea I have is that when anything changes in the desktop server database, the change is communicated to my tablet app.

Now, I don't know what would be a good form of communication between the server and the app (JSON?), but I think that before anyone would want to consider modifying their desktop app to be able to share data with mine, my app needs to actually work.

So I'm looking to write my first line of code, but I think before I do that, I need to decide on a database. In the tablet app, the user would only be performing read operations. The data itself would be small (short strings and some ints/longs) and structured and work well with a relational DB. Assuming the server communicates all updates immediately, there could be an update on average every 5 seconds for a normal event.

Comment: this type of question either falls into opinionated, or it falls into asking recommendations for software, both of which isn't allowed here, unfortunately. regarding, `So I'm looking to write my first line of code, but I think before I do that, I need to decide on a database.` if you structure your app correctly, you should be able to detach your database from the rest of the app, to the point where it doesn't really matter what you're using, you should be able to finish off your app and mock out your database till you can decide what's best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering how you described the problem, the data doesn't seem too complex or big; This is more of a "what do you prefer to work with" instead of "what do you need".

JSON in this case is a good format for your data, and if you like working with it, then that's a good solution.

If you want to use JSON format, MongoDB might be the best choice. Easy to learn, big community, pretty advanced and complete.